# Dimen value not working like expected

Tags: android

I'm having trouble understanding the dimen resource attribute.

I have 3 value folders: value-normal, value-large and value-xlarge.

I have defined the titlesize as 20 for normal, 25 for large and 30 for xlarge, this is my normal value file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="titleSize">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

But when I try to get this value

```
Resources r = getResources();
tvTitleSize = r.getDimension(R.dimen.titleSize);
```

tvTitleSize is equal to 40 which is offcourse to big. Why is the value the double of the original and how can I fix this?

Ps: my device is galaxy nexus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [docs of `Resource.getDimension()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension%28int%29) method, you find this:

> Resource dimension value multiplied by the appropriate metric.

In other words you are getting the actual size in pixels for the device.

The sp is density independent value. The value corresponds to mdpi, but Galaxy Nexus is xhdpi, which is twice as dense as mdpi. That's why you are getting 20 * 2 = 40;

If you are wondering, what is wrong, then the answer is nothing. The size you are getting is correct. The actual text size is different for ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi devices.

So for example 16dp means:

- 12px on ldpi
- 16px on mdpi
- 24px on hdpi
- 32px on xhdpi

The difference between `sp` and `dp` is that `sp` is affected by user preference for font size.

Answer (score 1):

The value you get back is measured in pixels. The `20sp` on a high density screen correspond to more pixels than on a low density screen. Android does the conversion for you.